# How to display an URL hyperlink as a custom clickable text

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, configuration

I am looking for solution regarding salesforce URL field update.
What I am doing :
whenever I am saving 3 dependent picklist values in three custom fields and these 3 values are saving as a URL.

My problem statement: I want to save values as a hyperlink but full link should not apear,only name of record should visible in these 3 fields.

We want behaviour like: account and contact lookup.

On contact record, we see only name and whenever we click on Account name, it redirects us on Account record same we are looking in our problem.

I tried with formula as well but url is coming.

Here is my lwc code:

```
<template>
<div>
<lightning-combobox label="Parent Role" value= 
  {selectedParentRoleId} options={parentRoles}
  onchange={handleParentRoleChange}>
 </lightning-combobox>
 </div>
 <lightning-combobox label="Child Role" value={selectedChildRoleId} 
 options={childRoles} onchange={handleChildRoleChange} disabled= 
 {isChildPicklistDisabled}>
 </lightning-combobox>
 <lightning-combobox label="Sub Child Role" value= 
 {selectedSubChildRoleId} options={subchildRoles}
 onchange={handleSubChildRoleChange} disabled= 
 {isSubChildPicklistDisabled}>
 </lightning-combobox>
 <lightning-button label="Save" variant="brand" onclick= 
 {handleSaveClick} disabled={isSaveDisabled}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

```
import {LightningElement, wire, track, api} from 'lwc';
import getParentRoles from '@salesforce/apex/UserRoleController.getParentRoles';
import getChildRoles from '@salesforce/apex/UserRoleController.getChildRoles';
import getSubChildRoles from '@salesforce/apex/UserRoleController.getSubChildRoles';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Id';
import link1 from '@salesforce/schema/Account.ParentRole__c';
import link2 from '@salesforce/schema/Account.ChildRole__c';
import link3 from '@salesforce/schema/Account.SubChildRole__c';
import {updateRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
export default class RolePicker extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track selectedParentRoleId;
    @track selectedChildRoleId;
    @track selectedSubChildRoleId;
    @track selectedSubSubChildRoleId;
    parentRoles = [];
    childRoles = [];
    subchildRoles = [];
    subsubchildRoles = [];
    isChildPicklistDisabled = true;
    isSubChildPicklistDisabled = true;
    isSubSubChildPicklistDisabled = true;
    @wire(getParentRoles)
    parentRolesResult({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            this.parentRoles = data.map(role => ({
                label: role.Name,
                value: role.Id
            }));
        } else if (error) {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
    handleParentRoleChange(event) {
        this.selectedParentRoleId = event.target.value;
        this.childRoles = [];
        this.selectedChildRoleId = null;
        this.subChildRoles = [];
        this.selectedSubChildRoleId = null;
        this.isChildPicklistDisabled = false;
        this.isSubChildPicklistDisabled = true;
        this.isSubSubChildPicklistDisabled = true;
        getChildRoles({
                parentRoleId: this.selectedParentRoleId
            })
            .then(result => {
                this.childRoles = result.map(role => ({
                    label: role.Name,
                    value: role.Id
                }));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // Handle error
            });
    }
    handleChildRoleChange(event) {
        this.selectedChildRoleId = event.target.value;
        this.subchildRoles = [];
        this.selectedSubChildRoleId = null;
        this.isSubChildPicklistDisabled = false;
        getSubChildRoles({
                parentRoleId: this.selectedParentRoleId
            })
            .then(result => {
                this.subchildRoles = result.map(role => ({
                    label: role.Name,
                    value: role.Id
                }));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // Handle error
            });
    }
    handleSubChildRoleChange(event) {
        this.selectedSubChildRoleId = event.target.value;
        this.subsubchildRoles = [];
        //this.selectedSubSubChildRoleId = null;
        this.isSubSubChildPicklistDisabled = false;
    }
    handleSaveClick() {
        if (!this.selectedParentRoleId && !this.selectedChildRoleId &&
            !this.selectedSubChildRoleId) {
            this.showToast('Error', 'Please select a value for at least one picklist.', 'error');
            return;
        }
        var labelRole = this.parentRoles.find(role => role.value ===
            this.selectedParentRoleId).label;

        const fields = {};
        fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.recordId;
        fields[link1.fieldApiName] = window.location.origin + '/lightning/r/UserRole/' +
            this.selectedParentRoleId + '/view';
        fields[link2.fieldApiName] = window.location.origin + '/lightning/r/UserRole/' +
            this.selectedChildRoleId + '/view';
        fields[link3.fieldApiName] = window.location.origin + '/lightning/r/UserRole/' +
            this.selectedSubChildRoleId + '/view';
        const recordInput = {
            fields
        };
        updateRecord(recordInput)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
                this.showToast('Success', 'Records saved successfully.', 'success');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
    showToast(title, message, variant) {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            variant: variant
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's something to add to your front end, not client controller. See this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: @DevelBase2 added code of html file

Comment: We have the requirement like this only, that's why we have cretaed dynamic url of enviroment in controller side

Answer (score 0):

A URL field would be incorrect for this case, as they can only show URLs. Instead, you could make a Rich Text Area field and generate proper links, such as:

```
const encode = (string) => {
  const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textarea.innerText = string;
  return textarea.innerHTML;
};

fields[link1.fieldApiName] = `<a href="/lightning/r/UserRole/${
    this.selectedParentRoleId
  }/view">${
    encode(
      this.parentRoles.find((role)=>role.value === this.selectedParentRoleId)?.label
    )
  }</a>`;
```

Comment: I also want to same behaviour in reports as well, can we do by rich text area field?

Comment: @RaviT It'll be a link anywhere RTF is supported, including reports.